# Get file name after remote file grabbing

Tags: php

I'm using the PHP file grabber script. I put URL of the remote file on the field and then the file is directly uploaded to my server. The code looks like this:

```
<?php
ini_set("memory_limit","2000M");
ini_set('max_execution_time',"2500");

foreach ($_POST['store'] as $value){
    if ($value!=""){
        echo("Attempting: ".$value."<br />");
        system("cd files && wget ".$value);
        echo("<b>Success: ".$value."</b><br />");
    }
}

echo("Finished all file uploading.");
?>
```

After uploading a file I would like to display direct url to the file : for example

> Finished all file uploading, direct URL:
>   http://site.com/files/grabbedfile.zip

Could you help me how to determine file name of last uploaded file within this code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to arbitrary command execution via `$_POST['store']`.

Comment: I had no idea just downloaded it from sourceforge :(

Comment: look up what `system()` does and then consider what happens when `$_POST['store']` contains `http://example.com && rm -rf /`

Comment: @TemurPipia It’s [altforge Remote PHP File Grabber](http://sourceforge.net/projects/remotephpgrab/), right?

Comment: Yes, exactly: http://sourceforge.net/projects/remotephpgrab/

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? What if someone uploads their own PHP file?

Comment: you could basename($value) - doesn't work all the times though.

Comment: @Jordan Doyle  what script should I use to have URL upload option on the server? :)

Comment: @TemurPipia Make sure PHP won’t get executed in the *files* directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wget log files. Just add `-o logfilename`.
Here is a small `function get_filename( $wget_logfile )`

```
ini_set("memory_limit","2000M");
ini_set('max_execution_time',"2500");

function get_filename( $wget_logfile )
{
    $log = explode("\n", file_get_contents( $wget_logfile ));
    foreach ( $log as $line )
    {
        preg_match ("/^.*Saving to: .{1}(.*).{1}/", $line, $find);
        if ( count($find) )
            return $find[1];
    }
    return "";
}

$tmplog = tempnam("/tmp", "wgetlog");
$filename = "";

foreach ($_POST['store'] as $value){
    if ($value!=""){
        echo("Attempting: ".$value."<br />");
        system("cd files && wget -o $tmplog ".$value); // -o logfile

        $filename = get_filename( $tmplog ); // current filename
        unlink ( $tmplog ); // remove logfile          

        echo("<b>Success: ".$value."</b><br />");
    }
}

echo("Finished all file uploading.");
echo "Last file: ".$filename;
```

Comment: Thanks. IT seems this is what I need, just a problem with the filename, because the file name was '3D-neon-fox.jgg' and after uploading the file name echo was '-neon-fox.j'

Comment: @TemurPipia Oh, my fault. Look at preg_match and change {3} to {1}

Comment: Thanks Andrey, great tip! :) And thanks to all guys for their help!

Comment: Still vulnerable to arbitrary command execution. Have a look at `escapeshellarg`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using wget like that, you could do it all using cURL, if that is available.

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

$lastDownloadFile = null;
foreach ($_POST['store'] as $value) {
    if ($value !== '' && downloadFile($value)) {
        $lastDownloadFile = $value;
    }
}

if ($lastDownloadFile !== null) {
    // Print out info
    $onlyfilename = pathinfo($lastDownloadFile, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
} else {
    // No files was successfully uploaded
}

function downloadFile($filetodownload) {
    $fp = fopen(pathinfo($filetodownload, PATHINFO_BASENAME), 'w+');
    $ch = curl_init($filetodownload);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // We're writing to our file pointer we created earlier
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Just in case the server throws us around
    $success = curl_exec($ch); // gogo!

    // clean up
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);

    return $success;
}
```

Some words of caution however, letting people upload whatever to your server might not be the best idea. What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Much as I'm a fan of cURL, the question is about displaying a URL to the last file in the loop, and this doesn't seem to address that at all.

Comment: Very true, should add something about that too. Comment area was to small to show a better way of handling the file fetching.

Comment: @hank, regarding why I let people upload their content to the site, I was looking for something like MFHS but only for URL uploads and find the script I mentioned above altforge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/remotephpgrab/?source=dlp

Comment: Still bad: I’ll give it something arbitrary like `https://raw.github.com/f4k1r/Terminal/master/terminal.php` as input and I’ll get a perfectly working shell.

Comment: @Gumbo, I understand . But, what solution you can offer?

Comment: Store the downloaded files in a folder not accessible from the webserver. When serving the files, serve them through PHP or use X-Sendfile or something like it